# how to give image a dynamic width and height when using bootstrap responsive grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap's grid system and here's [my website](http://www.shopious.com). The issue is that on initial load the item card looks pretty crappy like this:

[image]

and here's what it looks like after it loads:

[image]

As you can see the issue is because I am not supplying the image's width and height and hence before it load I am seeing this weird layout which is not good. The issue why I am not supplying a width and height is because this is responsive, such that when I resize the width of the browser then the width of the card also changes, and hence supplying a constant width and height doesn't work. What's the best solution out of this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can calculate your image ratio if it's known then set its padding to the ratio

Check out the js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/J8AYY/7/

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="">
</div>

.img-container {
    position:relative;
    padding-top:66.59%;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

So if your image has width 2197 pixels and height 1463 pixels

then set the container that contain the image to have padding-top 1463/2197*100%
then set your image to position absolute
now your image can be responsive and worry free of collapsing container

Answer (score 4):

You need to put your thumbnails in a dynamically sized container, *whose height is proportional to it's width*. You can do this by matching `width` and `padding-bottom` on the container, as well as a few other specifics as in the Bootply and example below:

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/q11Y8M2A0c)**

Example:

CSS:

```
.thumbnail_container {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 100%; <!-- matching this to above makes it square -->
     float:left;
}

.thumbnail {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

img{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- this makes your images scale constantly, between breakpoints as welll. removing -fluid makes then jump in size at breakpoints -->
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="thumbnail_container">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="thumbnail_container">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="thumbnail_container">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="thumbnail_container">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="no-photo" /> <!-- No Photo, but it still scales -->
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

You'll notice that in the last thumbnail, even though there is no file loaded, the container is square. This is the key that will fix your specific issue.

**Note:** matching `padding-bottom` to `width` will give you a square thumbnail container, but you can make it any proportion you want, by adjusting the `padding-bottom %`.

**Note2:** because you haven't shared your code, you'll probably have to do a bunch of class renaming and testing to get this to work.  I had to guess at your setup based on what I saw on your site. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with images that are all the same size, you can set a min-height on the image element for each step of the responsive page. You would have to find out how tall the images are at each step of the responsive page design, but it could look something like this:

```
.item-card img {
  min-height: 100px;
}

// Small screen
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item-card img {
    min-height: 150px;
  }
}

// Medium screen
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .item-card img {
    min-height: 200px;
  }
}

// Large screen
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .item-card img {
    min-height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems like I will be having tons of these

Comment: also in my case say I put a min height of 200px for 1100px medium screens, then I resize it to 1000px, the min-height for both will still be at 200px but one will look unproportional to the other

Comment: it looks like your cards are all the same height, regardless of how big the image is. seems this is a really good answer - you just have to find the right height(s)...

Comment: @ShawnTaylor the cards height will adjust based on the width of the screen, so they will adjust with the image width

Comment: right. i didn't notice that they change size throughout browser resize, not just at the breakpoints...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question you want the image to auto adjust when the browser is resized. We can achieve this using the css below.

```
.image-box img {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

If we only specify the width of the image the height will be auto calculated. It will maintain the aspect ratio for the image. Width 100% will exactly fit the container of the image. This code may not work for background image.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that at load time, the `img` has a height=0 and width=100%. So, you have an empty image when the page loads.

You can consider using an Image Preloader:

- [ImageLoaderJS](http://nick-jonas.github.io/imageloader/)
- [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS)

If you want all the images to have the same height, then use the [Fake Crop](https://github.com/VuongN/jQuery-Fakecrop/) jQuery plugin. Actually, it doesn't crop the image file, but the image gets a "cropped" effect using CSS Positioning properties.

Also, you can assign a `min-height` to the container:

```
 .product-view .img-responsive {min-height:352px; background:#fff;}
```

You can also look into Lazy Loading:

- [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)
- [Lazy Loading Images](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/)
- ...

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap 5.3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/images/#responsive-images):

> ## Responsive Images
>
> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with `.img-fluid`. This applies `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image so that it scales with the parent width.

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="...">
```

I know this doesn't directly answer the question based on the context given in the description, but it might still be useful to users that discovered this question based on the title alone and are looking for a direct answer to that.

Answer (score -1):

```
   use bootstrap or @media queries

  /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

 /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

   /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }

      We occasionally expand on these media queries to include a max-width to limit CSS to a narrower set of devices.

    @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
    @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
    @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }

     http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
```